# How to iterate inside an array of object containing multiple fields?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a resultList which fetches result from a JPQL query that queries multiple tables as described :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT protein.gid,protein.uniProtAccession,protein.name,protein.ECNumber,ttdtarget.uniProtID,ttdtarget.gid FROM Protein protein,TtdTarget ttdtarget WHERE protein.uniProtAccession = ttdtarget.uniProtID");
```

`List resultList = query.getResultList();`

Note: I am restricting the size of resultset to 5 right now, just for debugging. I want to get the values returned inside each object from the resultList, which basically is an array of objects.

So far I have tried iterating upto the objects but can't access the inner values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++)
{
System.out.println("->"+resultList.get(i));         
}
```

Output:

```
->[Ljava.lang.Object;@141ab9e
->[Ljava.lang.Object;@6a15ca
->[Ljava.lang.Object;@bcb654
->[Ljava.lang.Object;@1664b54
->[Ljava.lang.Object;@db953c
```

And here is the variable's output from debug:

[image]

So my question is how to access those values inside the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is `List<Object[]>`, so cast to that. So a list, where each element is an array of values. You must then cast each value to its type (which you know beforehand).

If you simply want to iterate and print:

```
List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
for (Object[] array : resultList) {
   for (Object field : array) {
      System.out.println("->"+field); 
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a new class which has these exact fields, make its constructor accept all of the values, and use it in the query: `SELECT new Foo(.....) FROM..`. There you can use the generic alternative of `em.createQuery(..)` that returns `TypedQuery`

Comment: You may not use the generic version of `createQuery()` for this kind of query. The javadoc says: "The select list of the query must contain only a single item, which must be assignable to the type specified by the resultClass argument."

Comment: thanks, I'll add it to the "alternative" (I started from that option in mind, and then messed up the order :) )

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a List of Objects, it is a List of Objectarrys

```
List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[])resultList;
for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++)
{
  System.out.print("protein.gid ->"+resultList.get(i)[0]);
  System.out.println("protein.uniProtAccession ->"+resultList.get(i)[1]);        
}
```

Comment: Well this part is giving error : resultList.get(i)[0]), can't access as array.

Comment: Sorry i forgott the cast

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
for (Object[] objects : resultList)
{
       for (Object object : objects)
       {
          System.out.println(object)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result form the query is array of objects.

```
List resultList = query.getResultList();

for(Object result : resultList) {
  Object[] results = (Object[]) result;
   for(Object res : results) {
     System.out.println(res);
   }
}
```

Or you can go with Bozho solution and create new direct from query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class with the exact fields you need and use a TypedQuery

```
TypedQuery<CustomClass> query = em.createQuery("" /* Query String */, CustomClass.class);
List<CustomClass> resultList = query.getResultList();
foreach (CustomClass result : resultList){
    // Need to override method toString() in CustomClass
    System.out.println("->" + result);         
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm tempted to suggest nesting a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < resutList.get(i).size(); j++){
    System.out.println("->"+resultList.get(i).get(j));
  }         
}
```

Comment: It's a `List<Object[]>`, not a `List<List<Object>>`.